# Error When Importing From Sketchup

Tags: 3d-view

Every time I try to import a sketchup model into blender, I get the error message below. Does anyone know how to solve it?

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\SketchUp_Importer\__init__.py", line 886, in execute
    context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\SketchUp_Importer\__init__.py", line 185, in load
    self.write_duplicateable_groups()
  File "C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\SketchUp_Importer\__init__.py", line 245, in write_duplicateable_groups
    group=group)
  File "C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\SketchUp_Importer\__init__.py", line 614, in conponent_def_as_group
    ob.layers = 18 * [False] + [True] + [False]
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'layers'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the forum! Could you provide some more information as to how you exported the sketchup model? What format did you use and using what settings?